# How to create two persistent store coordinator with on persistent store

Tags: core-data

I want to create two persistent store coordinator with one persistent store.[image]

But i am unable to add the store added one coordinator to add into another coordinator

```
- (void) initializeCoreData {
    if ([self managedObjectContext]) return;
    NSURL *modelUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelUrl];
    NSAssert(mom, @"%@:%@ No model to generate a store from", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *batchPersistentCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    NSAssert(coordinator, @"Failed to initialize coordinator");
    [self setManagedObjectContext:[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType]];
    [self setBatchUpdateManagedObjectContext:[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType]];
    [self setPrivateContext:[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType]];
    [[self batchUpdateManagedObjectContext] setPersistentStoreCoordinator:batchPersistentCoordinator];
    [[self privateContext] setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    [[self managedObjectContext] setParentContext:[self privateContext]];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = NULL;
    queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[self privateContext] persistentStoreCoordinator];
        NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = @(YES);
        options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = @(YES);
        options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = @{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"};
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *directoryArray = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
        NSURL *storeUrl = nil;
        storeUrl = [directoryArray lastObject];
        storeUrl = [storeUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyModel.sqlite"];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSPersistentStore *store = nil;
        store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error];
        NSAssert(store, @"Error initializing PSC: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

        psc = [[self batchUpdateManagedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]
        store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error];
        NSAssert(store, @"Error initializing PSC: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

        if (![self initCallBack]) return;

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self initCallBack]();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you unable? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing stopping you from doing exactly that so long as you are using a SQLite based store.  As Tom asked, what happened when you try?

Perhaps show your creation code?

Your code is nearly complete, you are only missing one step:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[self privateContext] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = @(YES);
    options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = @(YES);
    options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = @{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"};
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *directoryArray = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSURL *storeUrl = nil;
    storeUrl = [directoryArray lastObject];
    storeUrl = [storeUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyModel.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *store = nil;
    store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error];
    NSAssert(store, @"Error initializing PSC: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

    psc = [[self batchUpdateManagedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]
    store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error];
    NSAssert(store, @"Error initializing PSC: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

    if (![self initCallBack]) return;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self initCallBack]();
    });
});
```

Just grab a reference to the second `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and then call `addPersistentStoreWithType configuration: URL: error:` on it as well.  You can even use the exact same parameters.

Comment: I am big fan of your book on core data.Its been great help to me to learn new type of stacks. If you seen in my code i created two persistent store coordinator i.e. coordinator and batchPersistentCoordinator. I have set persistentStoreCoordinator of privateContext to coordinator and of  batchUpdateManagedObjectContext to  batchPersistentCoordinator. Now i am unable to add same sqlite store as addPersistentStoreWithType: method returns new instance of store.What should be the code for that?